# readfile text as dom in node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, dom

I am having trouble in reading file with node.js.

I have saved an HTML file and at the time of reading it I am using `fs.readFile`.

It is reading file but it renders it at view page as text. I want it to be `html DOM` element.

**Reading File-**

```
fs.readFile(result.Template, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                return console.log(err);
            }
            res.render('Website', { body: data });
        });
```

**Rendering on page-**

```
 <body>
        <%=body%>
    </body>
```

**From the image you can see that-**

[image]

How do I convert this text to HTML DOM element so that it renders easily.

Comment: Do you render a doctype, head and body elements as well ?

Comment: @adeneo, yes, The only part I am rendering under body. In this Image I want to show how text comes and rendered after.